# Pass C# byte array to C char* field

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling

I need to pass byte array from a C# application to a C DLL.

Here is the C structure:

```
typedef struct FOO_BAR
{
    uint32_t timestamp;
    char *payload;
    uint32_t payloadSize;
} FOO_BAR;
```

And the C# method which updates the values:

```
public void Update(uint newTimestamp, byte[] payload)
{
    var foobar = (FooBar) Marshal.PtrToStructure(_foobarHandle, typeof (FooBar));

    foobar.timestamp = newTimestamp;
    foobar.payloadSize = (uint) payload.Length;
    foobar.payload = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int) foobar.payloadSize);
    Marshal.Copy(payload, 0, foobar.payload, (int) foobar.payloadSize);

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(foobar, _foobarHandle, false);
}
```

C# structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FooBar
{        
    public uint timestamp;       
    public IntPtr payload;
    public uint payloadSize;
}
```

The problem is for `FOO_BAR.payload`. Marshaling is working well but the variable contains signed bytes instead of bytes.

As I can't modify the C program, how to get proper char values from bytes array?

The values on the DLL side are the following:

```
            Original byte (C#)  Marshalled byte (C)  UTF8.GetChars (C)
payload[0]  18                   18                  18
payload[3]  238                 -18                   0
payload[45] 215                 -41                   0
payload[80] 148                -108                  64
```

**Update**: marshalled bytes are correct although they are read signed. Closed question. See comments.

Comment: "Marshaling is working well but the variable contains signed bytes instead of bytes." - well yes, that's because you're using signed char in your C program. You'd need to change the data type to unsigned char. The underlying data bytes are identical - you're just reading them as signed. If the C program is written to work with that, why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I misinterpreted what I was reading. Values are correct.